# SQL calculation based on another column

Tags: sql

I am extracting data out of SQL database and need to calculate the opening balance of a stock item per project. I am getting the opening balance for the stock inclusive of all the projects.

```
item code | Project | Qty In | Qty Out
----------+---------+--------+---------
1234        1            0       90
1234        1           90        0
1234        2          431        0
1234        2            0       22
1234        3          925        0
1234        3            0      925
1234        3          925        0
1234        3            0       20
1234        3            0       40
1234        3            0       30
1234        3            0       40
1234        3            0       60
1234        3            0       50
1234        3            0       24
1234        3            0       40
1234        3            0       30
1234        3            0       17
1234        3            0       80
1234        3            0       30
1234        4           16        0
1234        4            0       16
1234        5           22        0
1234        5            0       23
```

Query:

```
select OpeningBalanceQty = Qty_On_Hand + 
(select case when ServiceItem = 0 
             then IsNull(sum (QtyOut), 0) 
             else 0 
        end 
 from table1 
 where AccountLink=StockLink  and txdate>='2016-06-01' and project ='2' ) - 
(select case when ServiceItem = 0 
             then IsNull(sum (QtyIn), 0) 
             else 0 
        end from table1 
 where AccountLink=StockLink  and txdate>='2016-06-01' and project ='2')
 from tablel join table2 on table1.AccountLink = table2.StockLink
```

I have used project 2 as an example, it has two transactions(qty in:431)& (qty out:22)

My opening balance should be 409 but it is giving the total for the product item

My full code:

```
select Table1.TxDate,Table2.Pack,Table1.Reference,

OpeningBalanceQty=  (select case when ServiceItem = 0 then IsNull(sum 
(QtyOut), 0) else 0 end from Table1 where AccountLink=StockLink  and 
ProjectCode in('2')   ) - (select case when ServiceItem = 0 then IsNull(sum 
(QtyIn), 0) else 0 end from Table1 where AccountLink=StockLink  and 
ProjectCode  in('2'))

,ProjectCode,ProjectDescription, Code, Description_1, Sum(ActualQuantity)*-1 
as [Qty Processed],Sum(Debit)-Sum(Credit) as [Value],Trcode

from Table1
join Table2
on Table1 .AccountLink = Table2.StockLink
where  ServiceItem = 0  and txdate>='2017-06-01 00:00:00' and txdate<='2017-
06-30 00:00:00' and Code='1234'
Group by Description_1, Code,ProjectCode, ProjectDescription, stocklink, 
serviceitem,Qty_On_Hand,Table1.Reference,Table2.Pack,Table1.TxDate,trcode
```

Comment: Please provide the expect output

Comment: the expected output is an opening balance of 409, i am currently getting 872 as the opening balance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think this could be helpful for you?

```
SELECT PROJECT, SUM( QTYIN-QTYOUT) AS OPEN_BAL_QTY
FROM yourtable
WHERE txdate>='2016-06-01'
GROUP BY PROJECT
```

Output:

```
PROJECT OPEN_BAL_QTY
1   0
2   409
3   464
4   0
5   -1
```

**1° update:** after your new information (pls, next time, try to give all the information in your initial post, and well formatted: see tour of stackoverflow to learn how to do).
If you are using MSSQL 2005 or later, you can try this:

```
SELECT TABLE1.TXDATE
    ,TABLE2.PACK
    ,TABLE1.REFERENCE 
       , SUM(QTYIN-QTYOUT) OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE1.PROJECTCODE) AS OPEN_BAL_QTY
    ,PROJECTCODE 
    ,PROJECTDESCRIPTION
    ,CODE
    ,DESCRIPTION_1
    ,-SUM(ACTUALQUANTITY) AS QTY PROCESSED
    , SUM(DEBIT) - SUM(CREDIT) AS VALUE
    ,TRCODE
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ACCOUNTLINK = TABLE2.STOCKLINK
WHERE SERVICEITEM = 0
    AND TXDATE >= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND TXDATE <= '2017-06-30 00:00:00'
    AND CODE = '1234'
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION_1
    ,CODE
    ,PROJECTCODE
    ,PROJECTDESCRIPTION
    ,STOCKLINK
    ,SERVICEITEM
    ,QTY_ON_HAND
    ,TABLE1.REFERENCE
    ,TABLE2.PACK
    ,TABLE1.TXDATE
    ,TRCODE
```

**2° update**
If it doesn't work for you, you should try:

```
 SELECT A.* 
        ,B.OPEN_BAL_QTY
    FROM  
        SELECT TABLE1.TXDATE
            ,TABLE2.PACK
            ,TABLE1.REFERENCE          
            ,PROJECTCODE 
            ,PROJECTDESCRIPTION
            ,CODE
            ,DESCRIPTION_1
            ,-SUM(ACTUALQUANTITY) AS QTY PROCESSED
            , SUM(DEBIT) - SUM(CREDIT) AS VALUE
            ,TRCODE
        FROM TABLE1
        JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ACCOUNTLINK = TABLE2.STOCKLINK
        WHERE SERVICEITEM = 0
            AND TXDATE >= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'
            AND TXDATE <= '2017-06-30 00:00:00'
            AND CODE = '1234'
        GROUP BY DESCRIPTION_1
            ,CODE
            ,PROJECTCODE
            ,PROJECTDESCRIPTION
            ,STOCKLINK
            ,SERVICEITEM
            ,QTY_ON_HAND
            ,TABLE1.REFERENCE
            ,TABLE2.PACK
            ,TABLE1.TXDATE
            ,TRCODE
    ) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJECTCODE, SUM( QTYIN-QTYOUT) AS OPEN_BAL_QTY
            FROM TABLE1
            WHERE TXDATE>='2017-06-01'
                AND TXDATE <= '2017-06-30 00:00:00'
            GROUP BY PROJECT) B ON A.PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_CODE
```

Comment: hie thank you for speedy response, i need to include the figure from Qty_On_Hand as well

Comment: pls post complete sample structures and data.  Otherwise, you can join the result of this query to your other table with QTY_ON_HAND, using - I suppose - PROJECT column.

Comment: @Tinashe ? where ?

Comment: sorry it was not fitting the comments - so i edited the question, everything is fine except in the openbalQty: if i specify a project like above it will give the opening balance for that specif project but on differnet projects aswell.

Comment: any ideas what i can do.

Comment: received with thanks i have seen both and i am testing.& i will definitely see tour of stackoverflow to learn how to's

Comment: option 1 worked was getting null value for opening balance then added  IsNull(sum (QtyOut),0 ) -  IsNull(sum (QtyIn), 0)  As OPEN_BAL_QTY